# Trying to use Firebase with AndroidX creates an error: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;

Tags: android, androidx

I was trying to use AndroidX libraries in my app, but I got a problem. I understood that problem connected with Firebase. As you see I excluded the support v4 library and I did this with a reason. If I remove these lines there will be another error: "Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$ConnectionCallback$StubApi21". So how can I use AndroidX and Firebase together? Is there any solution?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ignes.androidxtest, PID: 30800
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<clinit>(SourceFile:135)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SourceFile:273)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(SourceFile:37)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1696)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1671)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(SourceFile:31)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4619)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ignes.androidxtest-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ignes.androidxtest-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ignes.androidxtest-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ignes.androidxtest-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ignes.androidxtest-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ignes.androidxtest-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ignes.androidxtest-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ignes.androidxtest-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ignes.androidxtest-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ignes.androidxtest-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ignes.androidxtest-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.ignes.androidxtest-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<clinit>(SourceFile:135) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SourceFile:273) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(SourceFile:37) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1696) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1671) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(SourceFile:31) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4679) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4619) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 19 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

My build.gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.testng.androidxtest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
                force 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc01'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding this lib: `androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-rc01`

Comment: The proposed solution doesn't work. And how it can work?

Comment: Someone opened an issue on the google issue tracker

Comment: I have run into this today, can you remember the solution?

Comment: @AnnaFrolova u got solution ? please post it

Comment: Update June 2019: the same issue of `ArrayMap` is causing me errors, I've tried updating the Android Studio to latest 3.4.1 stable release, 3.5 & 3.6 beta releases yet no help. Also, both the flags in gradle configuration for AndroidX migration are enabled still no help. Any suggestions? PS: Once I disable or remove latest firebase dependencies, the project works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to updated my `Android Studio` to version `3.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

change your gradle version to: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha07'` and see if works.